# Find duplicate rows based on two columns and transfer results into another worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, vba

I have a worksheet ("Saisie de Données") containing data in column B and D that are sometimes duplicates. I would like to be able to recognize these duplicates and sum the data in the columns G to V. The result would then be transfered to another worksheet ("Sommaire - Paie") that will receive the non-duplicate rows with their related data and the duplicate row with the sum results. All the columns remains the same between the two worksheet except for the column C that is not copied to the new worksheet. Every time the macro will be launched, the data in the second worksheet ("Sommaire - Paie") will be overwritten.

I attached a copy of the worksheet with the data to be analysed ("Saisie de Données") and the espected result ("Sommaire - Paie") that I created manually.

To get the attached file, follow [this dropbox link](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/6307588/Promec%20-%20Rapport%20Heures%20-%20%282012-09-16%20au%202012-09-22%29%20-%20Example.xlsm).

In the real workbook, there are a lot more lines, but it's always the same pattern: the worker's name with the hours he did during the week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received some help from a guy called Yoyo Jiang and the code works perfectly. Here's the code I used:

```
Private Sub TestSumDuplicate()

Dim WS1 As Worksheet
Dim WS2 As Worksheet
Set WS1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Saisie de Données")
Set WS2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sommaire - Paie (2)")

Dim oRange1 As Range
Dim oRange2 As Range
Dim tempRange As Range

Set oRange2 = WS2.Range("A29", "U110")
oRange2.ClearContents
Set oRange1 = WS1.Range("A30", "V553")

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim t As Integer
Dim m As Integer
Dim n As Integer

Dim bFlag As Boolean

' j to record the current relative row location in oRange2
j = 1

For i = 0 To oRange1.Rows.Count - 1

bFlag = False '' to record if there is already a same category in oRange2.

If Not oRange1.Cells(i, 2) = "" Then
If Not oRange1.Cells(i, 2) = "Ligne Sommaire" Then

'' If it a row need to be check
For t = 1 To j
If oRange2.Cells(t, 3) = oRange1.Cells(i, 4) And oRange2.Cells(t, 2) = oRange1.Cells(i, 2) Then
bFlag = True

    '' Sum if duplicate
    For m = 0 To 18
    If Not oRange1.Cells(i, 7 + m) = "" Then
        oRange2.Cells(t, 6 + m) = oRange1.Cells(i, 7 + m) + oRange2.Cells(t, 6 + m)
    End If
    Next m

Exit For
End If
Next t

If bFlag = True Then
    bFlag = False
Else
    '' doesn't find a duplicate value
    oRange2.Cells(j, 1) = oRange1.Cells(i, 1)
    oRange2.Cells(j, 2) = oRange1.Cells(i, 2)

    For m = 4 To 25
     oRange2.Cells(j, m - 1) = oRange1.Cells(i, m)
    Next m

    j = j + 1
End If

End If
End If
Next i

End Sub
```